# Creating a new instance of implemented class, based on argument class type

Tags: java, design-patterns, generic-programming

I'll shortly describe how my code structure looks like:

- Class Aaa implements EventEmmiter
- Class Bbb implements EventEmmiter
- Class Aaa Event implements Event:

  ```
  public class AaaEvent implements Event {

      private final Aaa aaa;

      public AaaEvent(Aaa aaa) {
          this.aaa = aaa;
      }
  }
  ```
- Class BbbEvent implements Event:

  ```
  public class BbbEvent implements Event {
     private final Bbb bbb;
     public BbbEvent(Bbb bbb) {
     this.bbb = bbb;
     }
  }
  ```

I want to create a "createSomething" method to avoid code duplication. I want this method to create, depended of argument type (it can be Aaa or Bbb), a new instance of class which implements from Event.

**//EDITED**

Below you can find EventPublisher class which works properly but it's not look very nice. I want to avoid if/else or switch implementation cause it could grow more and more with the new classes.

```
public class EventPublisher {
    public void createSomething(EventEmitter eventEmitter) {
        DomainEvent event = null;
        Class<? extends EventEmitter> eventClass = eventEmitter.getClass();
        if (eventClass.isAssignableFrom(Aaa.class)) {
            event = new AaaEvents((Aaa) eventEmitter);
        } else if (eventClass.isAssignableFrom(Bbb.class)) {
            event = new BbbEvents((Bbb) eventEmitter);
        } else if () {
            some next (eg.CccEvents) class
        }

        domainEventBus.publish(event);
    }
}
```

For example. If type of EventEmmiter passed as a method argument is Aaa i want to create a new AaaEvent instance.

One more thing. I cannot use inside package of Aaa things from AaaEvent. It works on another direction. I can use things from Aaa package inside AaaEvent.

Can you give me some tips how to implement such things?

Comment: There is no direct connection between Aaa and AaaEvent as well as for Bbb and BbbEvent so I guess the only way to accomplish what you want is using some switch that will check `eventEmitter` class and create corresponding events

Comment: Also it just occurred to me - you can add some function to `EventEmitter` that will create event of desired class, then override this function in Aaa and Bbb

Comment: I edited my question. Now you see that there are Aaa parameter in Aaa Events. And for the second answer it's impossible- look at my answer to @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: The first (and most important) structural problem: Your events know about the event emitter. An event should be a light-weight class without any further dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You want to implement the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
public interface EventEmmiter {
    Event createEvent();
    ...
}

public class Aaa implements EventEmitter {
    @Override public AaaEvent createEvent() { return new AaaEvent(); }
    ...
}

public class Bbb implements EventEmitter {
    @Override public BbbEvent createEvent() { return new BbbEvent(); }
    ...
}
```

Now you can simply use it as:

```
public void createSomething(EventEmitter eventEmitter) {
    Event someEvent = eventEmitter.createEvent();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that Aaa cannot create new instance of AaaEvent because of packages dependencies. Let's say that inside Aaa module i cannot use AaaEvent module stuffs. It works only in another direction. That's why I was thinking of generic way of implementation

Comment: Then you seem to have a structural problem that you should solve first. This pattern is definitively the way to go.

Comment: I edited my post a little bit to better describe my problem.